# Change of Occupation Notice

Tags: passports, us-citizens

I'm a US passport holder. I have changed my occupation since receiving my passport. Not just my job, but the actual industry and occupation therein.

They are totally different fields, so much so that if I were to fill out my passport application today, I'd use an entirely different word to describe my occupation.

At border crossings into other countries I have been asked about my listed occupation.  I understand that the occupation is not listed on my passport, but I have been asked about it at entry interviews, so I know it is on a database somewhere. The new occupation may raise fewer eyebrows, so I would like that reflected in the database when I travel.

I have emailed the National Passport Information Center but they can't seem to answer my question. I understand such a notice is not required, but I would like to give one anyway.

Does anyone know how to go about doing that?

Comment: A country asking about your occupation is not related to data the US passport agency has, it is simply information that country wants to know.

Answer (score 5):

There is no mechanism to provide notice to the Department of State that you have changed your occupation from that listed on your passport application.* It's simply understood and expected that this happens. Adult passports last for 10 years. Much of the information on the application is likely to become out of date in this time, and that's just fine; you [don't even need to notify them if you change your address](https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/passports/services/correction.html).

Crossing borders, you might be asked about your occupation, either in person or on entry forms. Just give your current occupation. In the quite unlikely situation a country has your old occupation on file and asks you about it, you can tell them you got a new job.

[*] You could, I suppose, apply for a new passport and put whatever you want in the occupation field, but this is an entirely unnecessary expense and hassle that will give you no benefit.